# Redirect using variables in NGINX

Tags: variables, nginx, redirect, configuration

I try to create a redirection in my NGINX server using a regular expression.

More specifically I want to redirect the URLs that follow the pattern `example.com/a/b/c` to `example.com/b/c`. I believe that in order to do it I need to save the rest of the URL (in the example `/b/c`) in a variable.

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, and `c`? Are they each wildcards (e.g. `[^/]+`). Maybe something like: `rewrite ^/[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+)$ $1 redirect;`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, what you are trying to achieve, is made like so

```
location ~ /somelocation/(.*)$ {
    return 301 https://example.com/$1;
}
```